# Issues with source command for setting up ros2 workspace

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, ros2

I'm going through the ROS2 tutorial [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html#source-the-environment), as far as I know Ive been following it line by line but I'm running into issues trying to run a setup script for the workspace.

When I try to run the bash script the source command seems to look within a directory I dont specify when theres a setup.bash script in the specified directory. I tried getting more info with help but theres nothing I can see that would explain why its looking for a file deeper in than I specified.

> ```
> nathan@nathan-desktop:~/ros2_ws$ ls
> build  install  log  src
> nathan@nathan-desktop:~/ros2_ws$ source /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash 
> nathan@nathan-desktop:~/ros2_ws$ source install/setup.bash
> not found: "/home/nathan/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client/share/examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client/local_setup.bash"
> nathan@nathan-desktop:~/ros2_ws$
> ```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: Thanks, you'd think that'd be included on the page for originally posting a question